# SQL HELP: How to SUM two different rows together as one value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add the values of two different rows together in oracle live sql.

[image: click to view table]

As the image shows, I have this table and I want specifically the total of Example1  for FirstEx and SecondEx rows, in one value, the total would be: 10.

I know i can achieve this by

```
SELECT SUM(Example1) FROM ExampleTable;
```

But i plan to add more rows to cName and ones with different names so i want to know how to add specifically **FirstEx** and **SecondEx** together,
the closest i got was:

```
SELECT cName, SUM(Example1) AS Total
FROM Example Table
GROUP BY cName;
```

However, the code that I wished to use as it seemed to make sense to do this was:

```
SELECT SUM(Example1) AS TOTAL
FROM ExampleTable
WHERE cName = 'FirstEx' AND 'SecondEx';
```

however it produces an error, can anyone fix this for me?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it almost right

The SUM in your SELECT requires a GROUP BY
Your WHERE CLAUSE is not right every coparison has to have a column name

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Example1) AS Total
FROM
    Example_Table
WHERE
    cName = 'FirstEx' OR cName = 'SecondEx';
```

OR you make

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Example1) AS Total
FROM
    Example_Table
WHERE
    cName IN ('FirstEx','SecondEx');
```